# Generalised Linear Models in R with Categorical Response Variables

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model

I have some seed dispersal data and I am attempting to solve the question of "What variables best predict the following: a lemur specialist-dispersed seed (only 1 lemur species disperses the given seed species), a lemur generalist grade-1 dispersed seed (between 2-3 lemur species disperse the given seed species), and a lemur generalist grade-2 dispersed seed (between 4-5 lemur species disperse the given seed species).

My data is a mix of some categorical and some numeric predictor variables, and the response variable (L_FEEDER) is one of 6 levels, either NDL for not dispersed by lemurs, LS for lemur specialist, and then LG1, LG2, LG3, and LG4 (meaning 2, 3, 4, or 5 lemur species disperse the seed).

```
    > str(df1)
'data.frame':   405 obs. of  35 variables:
 $ MALAGASY_NAME  : Factor w/ 91 levels "Ambilazona","Ambovitsika",..: 7 7 42 78 78 78 78 38 38 38 ...
 $ FAMILY         : Factor w/ 45 levels "Anacardiaceae",..: 19 19 16 22 22 22 22 12 12 12 ...
 $ PLANT_TYPE     : Factor w/ 7 levels "E","ET","H","PT",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ FRUIT_TYPE     : Factor w/ 3 levels "C","D","F": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ F_WEIGHT.g.    : num  16.06 9.71 0.59 21 NA ...
 $ F_LENGTH.cm.   : num  43 39 15 39 NA NA NA 19 NA 19 ...
 $ F_WIDTH.cm.    : num  3 2.5 0.8 3.7 NA NA NA 1.5 NA 1.6 ...
 $ SEED_FRUIT     : num  22 20 1 4 NA NA NA 2 NA 2 ...
 $ S_LENGTH.cm.   : num  0.3 NA 1.3 1.9 1.9 1.9 1.9 1.1 0.7 1.1 ...
 $ S_WIDTH.cm.    : num  6 NA 6 16 15 16 15 6 6 5 ...
 $ S_INDWEIGHT.g. : num  NA NA 0.21 2.33 2.21 2.34 1.96 0.26 0.24 0.21 ...
 $ S_TOTWEIGHT.g. : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA 8.81 NA 0.49 NA ...
 $ SEED_COLOUR    : Factor w/ 8 levels "Bl","Br","DR",..: 8 8 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ COLOUR_URF     : Factor w/ 6 levels "Br","G","Gr",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ COLOUR_RF      : Factor w/ 12 levels "B","Br","DR",..: 4 4 10 4 4 4 4 12 12 12 ...
 $ Erb            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Erf            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Pe             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Vv             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Ap             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ L_FEEDER       : Factor w/ 6 levels "LG1","LG2","LG3",..: NA NA 3 5 5 5 5 3 3 3 ...
 $ Hm             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Am             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Pc             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Cn             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Zm             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": NA NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ B_FEEDER       : Factor w/ 6 levels "BG1","BG2","BG3",..: NA NA 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 ...
 $ FRUIT_SIZE.cm2.: num  129 97.5 12 144.3 NA ...
 $ SEED_SIZE.cm2. : num  1.8 NA 7.8 30.4 28.5 30.4 28.5 6.6 4.2 5.5 ...
 $ F_WEIGHT_Avg   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Above Average",..: 1 1 2 1 NA NA NA 2 NA 2 ...
 $ F_SIZE_Avg     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Above Average",..: 1 1 2 1 NA NA NA 2 NA 2 ...
 $ SEED_FRUIT_Avg : Factor w/ 2 levels "Above Average",..: 1 1 2 2 NA NA NA 2 NA 2 ...
 $ S_SIZE_Avg     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Above Average",..: 2 NA 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ S_INDWEIGHT_Avg: Factor w/ 2 levels "Above Average",..: NA NA 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ S_TOTWEIGHT_Avg: Factor w/ 2 levels "Above Average",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 NA 2 NA ...
```

I imagine I will subset the data to only include, say, LG1 and LG2 to answer the subquestion of what variables best predict a lemur generalist- grade1 dispersed seed. Would I then be doing a binomial Bernoulli GLM, as this would limit the response variable to be either option a or b? Or is there a way to perform a GLM without subsetting the data and using L_FEEDER as the response variable as it is (a categorical variable with 6 levels)?

Thank you

Comment: Isn't your task rather a classification task? And then what is the range of the outcomes that your variable ate believed to have a causal relationship with? My understanding from your text is that you should try to fit one vs all classification model for each lemur type. Not a regression for just two types.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean that I should have each observation of Lemur feeding type (LS, LG1, LG2, etc) as the response variables? So I would subset the data as in: (df2 <- subset(df1, L_FEEDER == LS)), etc. ?

Comment: You don't need to subset the data at all, use all of it for training. Read up on multiclass classification problem or on  binary classification "one vs all". They are very well researched and discussed topics.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a bit of reading time into the multiclass classification.